# Consume @Published values on the main thread?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

Is there a way to specify that count should only publish on the *main thread*? I've seen docs that talk about setting up your Publisher using `receive(on:)`, but in this case the `@Publisher` wrapper hides that logic.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class MyCounter: ObservableObject {
  @Published var count = 0

  public static let shared = MyCounter()
  
  private init() { }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var state = MyCounter.shared
    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            Text("Current count: \(state.count)")
            Button(action: increment) {
                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Text("Increment")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .bold()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func increment() {
        NetworkUtils.count()
    }
}

public class NetworkUtils {

    public static func count() {
        guard let url = URL.parse("https://www.example.com/counter") else {
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                let statusCode = response.statusCode
                if statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 300 {
                    do {
                        guard let responseData = data else {
                            return
                        }
                        
                        guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
                            return
                        }
                        
                        if let newCount = json["new_count"] as? Int{
                            MyCounter.shared.count = newCount
                        }
                    } catch  {
                        print("Caught error")
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        task.resume()
    }   
}
```

As you can see from my updated example, This is a simple SwiftUI view that has a button that when clicked makes a network call.  The network call is asynchronous. When the network call returns, the `ObservableObject MyCounter` is updated on a background thread. I would like to know if there is a way to make the `ObservableObject` publish the change on the main thread. The only way I know to accomplish this now is to wrap the update logic in the network call closure like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    MyCounter.shared.count = newCount
}
```

Comment: Show the code where you're setting `MyCounter.count`.

Comment: I was setting the value from the closure of a network call, which of course wouldn't be on the main thread.

Comment: OK, add that code to your question. We can't help you fix something that you don't include.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)`, you can use `URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession)) which will allow you to create a Combine pipeline. Then you can chain the `receive(on:)` operator as part of your pipeline.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
  .map { response in ... }
  ...
  .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
  ...
```

Also check out [heckj's examples](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#patterns-datataskpublisher-decode), I've found them to be very useful.

Comment: I think this is the best way

Answer (score 5):

If you try to set value marked `@Published` from a background thread you will see this error:

> Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure
>   to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive

So you have to make sure anywhere you set the value that it this done on the main thread, the values will always be published on the main thread.

Comment: Right.  That's the error I'm seeing and I want to know if there is a way to configure the Publisher used when you use the @Published wrapper to automatically move the update to the main thread.  Right now, I'm just updating those fields I use by switching to the main thread using DispatchQueue.main.async {}.

Answer (score 0):

The `Combine` way to accomplish this (for API that do not provide Publishers) could be replacing

```
MyCounter.shared.count = newCount
```

with

```
Just(newCount).receive(on: RunLoop.main).assign(to: &MyCounter.shared.$count)
```

And here is how we can do it using Modern Concurrency async/await syntax.

```
import SwiftUI

final class MyCounter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var count = 0
    public static let shared = MyCounter()
    
    private init() {}
    
    @MainActor func setCount(_ newCount: Int) {
        count = newCount
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var state = MyCounter.shared
    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            Text("Current count: \(state.count)")
            Button(action: increment) {
                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Text("Increment")
                        .bold()
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(.bordered)
        }
    }
    
    private func increment() {
        Task {
            await NetworkUtils.count()
        }
    }
}

class NetworkUtils {
    
    static func count() async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/counter") else {
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        
        do {
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
            await MyCounter.shared.setCount(Int.random(in: 0...100)) // FIXME: Its just for demo
            if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
               response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300 { throw URLError(.badServerResponse) }
            guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] else {
                throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(.init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected [String: Any]"))
            }
            if let newCount = json["new_count"] as? Int {
                await MyCounter.shared.setCount(newCount)
            }
        } catch  {
            print("Caught error :\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try this in my project (which involves `actor`s), I get this: `Actor-isolated property '$mostRecentActivity' can not be used 'inout' from a non-isolated context; this is an error in Swift 6`